# calculate sum from attribute JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sum

How can I calculate the sum from many different get-attributes that I put in a li-table? I want to update the total each time I add/remove in the li table... Here is the code:
Javascript:

```
var ele = info[plus.indexOf(this)];

var ul = document.getElementById("cart_id");

var li = document.createElement("LI");

var title = ele.getAttribute("data-title");

var price = parseInt(ele.getAttribute("data-price"));

li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(title+" "+price));   
ul.appendChild(li);//So far so good!!


/*Update! when I try this code below, I get current value from (data-price) X 3? 
So when I press 299 I get value 897? Why does it count like this? 
I want to sum the total!? I guess I have to put [i] inside there 
but I don't know which way, I doesn't work if I try:  
total += parseInt(listItem[i].ele.getAttribute("data-price")); */

  var total = 0;

  listItem = ele.getAttribute("data-price");

  for (var i=0; i < listItem.length; i++) 
  { 
  total += parseInt(ele.getAttribute("data-price")); 
  }

    document.querySelector("#totalPrice").value = total;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="cart">
<div id="cart">Cart</div>
<ul class="cart_ul" id="cart_id">
</ul>

<form>
<br>Total price:
<input type="text" name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice" disabled> 
</form>
</div>

<ul class="product" id="prod">
  <li class="first" data-title="iPad" data-price="299">iPad euro;299)/li>
</ul>
```

So I want to get the price (data-price="299" in this case) from "product UL-class" and put it in "cart UL-class".

Comment: you need to post ur html as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fully working plunker for you

http://plnkr.co/edit/MnrUyl40AbV6jEYGEGHU?p=preview

```
function recalculareTotal(){

  var total = 0,
      lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++ ){
    total += parseInt(lis[i].getAttribute("data-price"));
  }

  document.querySelector("#totalPrice").value = total;
}
```

it's without jQuery and does everything you need - adds and removes items and calculates the total each time.

***Update***

1. "li" tag in your code is not closed

   <li class="first" data-title="iPad" data-price="299">iPad euro;299)/li>
2. I don't  know what's exactly "ele" variable means in your code, but first you should get the entire list (UL), then interate over it's elements (LI) and get the "data-price" attribute of *each* LI in that list.

Updated plunker, see function `recalculareTotal2`

http://plnkr.co/edit/PRBcOSIMWsEKPJsCGT9I?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still cant get it to work. I get NaN as output!

Comment: You get Nan in your code or my plunker example? What browser do you use?

Comment: I get NaN in my code. I use Mozilla...
lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); Im not sure what to use as TagName here. If you look at my HTML code?? Thanks!

Comment: I can't try your code cause it's not complete (can you create a plunker?), but the first thing I notice looking at your code: `var price = parseInt(ele.getAttribute("data-price"));` so price is an integer, right? After `var arr = price;` "arr"  is an integer also. Then you are making a loop `for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){` but arr.lenght should throw an exception since it's not an array.

Comment: Hi, I still can't get it to work, could you please look at my updated code? Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it now. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You could either add new price to existing total or re-calculate total price again. For example:

```
function getSum() {
   var totalPrice = 0;
   $('li').each(function () {
      totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'));
   });
   return totalPrice;
}
```

Without jquery:

```
var list= document.getElementById("ul");
var listItem = list.getElementsByTagName("li");

var totalPrice = 0;

for (var i=0; i < listItem.length; i++) { 
    totalPrice += parseInt(listItem[i].getAttribute('data-price')); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, any Idea without Jquery? Only JavaScript?

Comment: @toppen Added without jquery!

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error: TypeError: list is null

Comment: @toppen You need to update the first line according to your html. Post your html and we can help.

Comment: **ALWAYS** set a base on `parseInt`. If a value is `09`, your code won't work. It will interpret `09` as being 9 in octal, which is invalid. Then it returns `NaN`. Now, `totalPrice` will be `NaN`. Result: Now what you expect. Set the base as `10` and add `||0` at the end, in case it returns `NaN`. You would call then `totalPrice += parseInt(listItem[i].getAttribute('data-price'), 10) || 0;`.

Comment: @WhatisSober I did post the relevant part of html code.. Can you please look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code `price` is `int` (from `var price = parseInt(ele.getAttribute("data-price"));`) and you assign it to an array `arr` in `var arr = price;`.

You probably meant to populate `arr` with an array of elements.

Comment: How do I do that? Or how can I show the total from getAttribute("data-price"));? Do I have to use array? Thanks!